# Is a document _id safe to be used as a parameter in an URL?

Tags: elasticsearch

*Note: by "safe" I mean "it will not break the URL" and not any information security aspects*

I would like to use the documents autogenerated `_id` in URLs (as a parameter), in constructions such as `http://example.com?theid=JHKJhY45FGf` where `JHKJhY45FGf` is the `_id` of a document

(please note that this is not an ES query but merely the reuse, in a URL context, of the `_id`).

**Is there a set of characters the `_id` is built on and are they part of the [safe character set](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-12) for URLs?**

If the answer is "no" then I will encode the `_id`, but would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autogenerated document id is URL safe, see [Autogenerating IDs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-doc.html#_autogenerating_ids)

> Autogenerated IDs are 20 character long, **URL-safe**, Base64-encoded GUID
>   strings. These GUIDs are generated from a modified FlakeID scheme
>   which allows multiple nodes to be generating unique IDs in parallel
>   with essentially zero chance of collision.